# Find the number of occurrences in a csv file

Tags: powershell

I have this code that will count the number of records for each email address.

This is how the csv looks like:

```
PST   EmailAddress
pst1  email1
pst2  email1
pst3  email1
pst4  email1
pst5  email2
pst6  email2
```

My code:

```
$csvFile = import-csv "csvFile"

prevEmail = ""

foreach ($row in csvFile){
 $currEmail = $row.emailAddress
 $PSTCounter = 1
 if ($prevEmail -eq $currEmail)
   $PSTCounter++

 elseif ($prevEmail -ne ""){
  func($prevEmail, $PSTCounter)
  $prevEmail = $currEmail

}
}
```

Result should be:

```
func(email1,4)
```

But the problem here is with the first record won't match the if statements, and I can't put the `$prevEmail` inside the foreach since it'll  reset every time. If the csv was an array instead I'd use nested loops for this, but not sure how to do that in this case.

Comment: If you use the ```Group-Object``` cmdlet you can group by email address and just get the count of items for each group - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this, taked by your code:

```
# import CSV file List
$csvFile = import-csv "csvFile.csv"
# take the second column and put elements in array
$emailList = @($csvFile.emailAddress)
# count occurrence
$emailList | Group-Object
```

---

Output will be:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
4 email1                    {email1, email1, email1, email1}
1 email2                    {email2}
1 email3                    {email3}
```